# Problemas com Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin-studio

Instalei o Xamarin no Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015 e estou tentando utilizar no Windows para programar em multiplataforma. Porém me deparei com bastante bugs, não encontro nenhum tutorial ensinando a configurar desde a instalação o ambiente, e também no "tools" onde se tem os componentes para colocar na tela, nem aparece. Alguem que tem conhecimento poderia me dar uma ajuda? Colocarei alguns prints aqui.

[image: Image 1]

[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]

[image: Image 4]

Comment: Já instalou algum update? Tente baixar o update 3: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/releasenotes/vs2015-update3-vs

Comment: Estou tendo o mesmo problema estou desinstalando VS2017 e instalando o VS Community 2015. :'(

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/getting_started/visual_studio_with_xamarin/